# Select a combo box item XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying to do a CASE for the option quality but Im receiving a operator error of "==" what is the solution for this problem.?

This is the code behind

```
  private void myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.SelectedValue.ToString == Low)
        {
            QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityHigh);

            case
                (myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.SelectedValue.ToString == Medium)
            {
                QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityMedium);
            }
            case
               (myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.SelectedValue.ToString == High)
            {
                QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityHigh);
            }

        }
```

And this is my xaml code.

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml" SelectionChanged="myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml_SelectionChanged" >
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="LW">Low</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="MD">Medium</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="HG">High</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some C# syntax problems going there.  You need `()` for the `ToString` method, and quote-marks around the string literals:

```
if (myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Low")
```

If you wanted to use a switch statement, then it's like this:

```
switch(myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.SelectedValue.ToString())
{
    case "Low":
        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityHigh);
        break;
    case "Medium":
        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityMedium);
        break;
    case "High":
        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.QualityHigh);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```